# Combining probabilities from 2 models to get one final probability

Tags: probability

I have a question about probabilities.

So I have one model which predicts probability of event A with 0.70 and event B with 0.30.

Then I have another model which predicts probability of the same event A with 0.66, but event B with 0.55 because the second model predicts probability between A and B independently, hence the sum of A and B can be bigger than 1 in this case.

Now my question is, is there a way to adjust the first probability based on the second one?

So in my case the first probability 0.70 would be lower because the second model gave me 0.66 and the probability for event B is higher because the second model gave me probability 0.55. I thought about averaging but in the end I will end up with probabilities which are either lower/higher than 1. I just want to adjust the first model probabilities by second model but still predict 100%.

I hope this was clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on what you are doing and how you obtained these outputs. But in the end, you cannot have probabilities for the second model which do not sum to 1. A simple fix is to normalize the second model probabilities to sum to 1, and then take the average of the two models, which will ensure that the sum is still 1.

```
a=c(0.7,0.3)
b=c(0.66,0.55)
b=b/sum(b)

(a+b)/2
[1] 0.6227273 0.3772727
sum((a+b)/2)
[1] 1
```

Comment: hm.. yeah I like that idea. I don't know why I haven't thought about it earlier. Thanks.